# My user is not in the sudoers file

Tags: sudo, password

```
ana is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

So, what can I do?

To change the password I need to edit the sudoers file, and to edit the file I need the password!

Answer (score 2):

Combining the comment from @steeldriver and [this thread.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

> You need to use recovery mode from Ubuntu.
>
> First, you have to hold shift when booting. You will be seeing this menu. Then select a menu with (recovery mode) in it. Preferred the 2nd from top.
>
> [image]
>
> Then, you should see this menu. Choose root. 
>   [image]
>
> After that, you'll see a root prompt, something like this :
>
> ```
> root@ubuntu:~#
> ```
>
> You see, using recovery will get you in read-only state. You need to make your system read write with this command.
>
> ```
> mount -o rw,remount /
> ```
>
> Then, you can readd your user to sudo with this command.
>
> ```
> adduser YOUR_USERNAME sudo
> ```
>
> Reboot as usual and you'll be able to use `sudo`.

Comment: why a freaking downvote?

Comment: you can execute that command on simple terminal if you are inside postgres user account type "exit", on other user type that command: SUDO adduser postgres sudo

Answer (score 0):

As I get your question, Ana wishes to use `sudo` without being allowed yet. This requires root rights to be changed (fortunately!). I also understand you are `root`, and you are possibly `ana`.

Should my understanding be right:

- Ana can do this if he/she has the root password

  su
  adduser ana sudo
- Or you can do this for Ana if you are root or sudoer but not him/her

  sudo adduser ana sudo

`su` switches to `root`, and therefore requires knowing the root password, and `adduser ana sudo` adds `ana` to the `sudo` group.

And should my understanding of your question be wrong, 1) sorry and 2) please let me know and I'll delete that answer.