# user is not in the sudoers file. tried to solve it, same result

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

I tried [user is not in the sudoers file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463613/user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file) and 
[My user is not in the sudoers file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934643/my-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file) with the same result:

```
root@avilellaM710t:/home/avilella# sudo adduser avilella sudo         
The user `avilella' is already a member of `sudo'.
root@avilellaM710t:/home/avilella# exit a
vilella@avilellaM710t:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for avilella:  avilella is not in the sudoers file.
This incident will be reported. 
avilella@avilellaM710t:~$ whoami
avilella
```

Also, see:

```
root@avilellaM710t:/home/avilella# cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "The change will take effect the next time the user logs in."

Comment: You are using sudo as `root` to execute `adduser` (unnecessary), thats why you are getting the error. `usermod -aG sudo aviella` will add the user to the group sudo, without deleting any other existing group the user belongs to. `su -l aviella` to clear envvars and initialize HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME and PATH. `id` to check the groups your user is in.

Comment: It worked after rebooting, so with a fresh user login.